# Why are SQL Compact 3.5 SP2 assemblies stamped with AssemblyVersion 3.5.1.0?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, .net-assembly, servicepacks, assemblyversionattribute

Having upgraded SQL Compact 3.5 SP1 to 3.5 SP2 I have noticed that the assembly versions are the same:

```
....
AssemblyVersion("3.5.1.0")]
....
SatelliteContractVersion("3.5.1.0")]
....
```

The only difference at first glance is the modification date (Jun.2008 for SP1, Feb.2010 for SP2).

Any reason why would Microsoft not stamp SP2 with 3.5.2.0 assembly version?

How am I supposed to rebuild the project with SP2 so that it would **require** an updated version of SQLCE 3.5 SP2 on the device pool running my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AssemblyVersion` represents the interface of the assembly. This is not expected (generally) to change for pure defect fixes.

The file (and possibly product) version would change in this case: the interface has not changed, but this is newer.